# Remove text from cells that don't contain S, M, L, XL or XXL

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a column that has about 500k rows. I need to make every row BLANK that doesn't contain S, M, L, XL or XXL

I don't want to remove the row, just replace them with nothing

Comment: I haven't tried much i'm not that good with excel. I no how to find and replace but how can i keep only the few things i want and remove the rest.

Comment: Personally I would try to filter the data and then just delete what you don't need

Comment: you want to clear **the cell** if it does not have one from the list, or clear the entire row, leaving a gap?

Answer (score 3):

Add a filter to the column, deselect the ones you don't want to erase.  Select all the data and hit delete.

Comment: This answer would be better if you could include a quick screenshot of the filter in action.

Answer (score 2):

You can use IF with Find, but notice that Find is case sensitive, so you have to write S, M, L, XL, XXL the same way in the Formula like in the cells, you can use the following but it is a nesting If, supposing your data is in column A in B write:
`=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("S",A1,1)),A1,IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("M",A1,1)),A1,IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("L",A1,1)),A1,IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("XL",A1,1)),A1,IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("XXL",A1,1)),A1,"")))))`
And you can drag it down.

Comment: How does this clear the data from the cell if it doesn't meet the criteria described by the OP?

Comment: @CharlieRB it makes Blank if the cell does not contain S, M, L, XL, XXL what else is the criteria???

Comment: I think your approach is valid.....if the Poster wants to clear cells in the **original** data *(that is column **A**)*; all they need to do is to copy column **B** and `PasteSpecialValues` onto column **A** ............to remove cells rather than clear them would require something a little more complex.

Comment: Sure with copy and paste special values the user can have the column clear as he wants it

Comment: All I was looking for was you to explain that in your answer rather than leave it to the OP to figure out.

Comment: I waited for OP to ask so I can explain it, but it seems he gave up